# Удалить дубликаты со сменой слов (напр. «Иван Иванов» и «Иванов Иван»)

Tags: excel

Есть 2 строки: «Иван Иванов» и «Иванов Иван». Каким образом можно удалить любой из дубликатов и оставить только один?

[image]

Comment: Столбцов только два? Строк сколько?

Comment: @vikttur да (два столбца, две строки). Прикрепил изображение к сообщению, оно отображается у Вас?

Comment: Странный вопрос... Или Вы что-то не описали. Удалите одну строку или значения в ней

Comment: Любым образом. Выделить строку и нажать на кнопку Delete или выделить строку, нажать на правую кнопку мыши и на Удалить строку или удалить содержание каждой ячейки по отдельности.

Comment: @vikttur на счёт одной строки понятно. Просто таких значений может быть 80 000 - не будешь ведь вручную их удалять.

Comment: @Эникейщик как можно автоматизировать этот процесс, если таких повторяющихся значений будет крайне много?

Comment: Тут макрос нужен, формулы на таком объеме будут тормозить. На вопрос сколько строк Вы ответили - две. Оказывается, тысячи. Может, и столбцов для сравнения больше? Повторы стоят рядом или могут быть разбросаны? Две дублирующиеся строки или может быть больше? Дубли есть у всех или могут быть без дублей? Дополните свою задачу ответами на эти вопросы, иначе ее судьба - закрытие, т.к. проблема не раскрыта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Казалось бы, вопрос достаточно прост. Если критерия (графы) всего два, то проще всего последовательно проверить каждый вариант комбинирования.

```
if (Range("a1") & " " & Range("b1") = Range("a2") & " " & Range("b2")) or (Range("b1") & " " & Range("a1") = Range("a2") & " " & Range("b2")) then
    'удалить дублирующую строчку
end if
```

Данный код можно засунуть в цикл и последовательно проверять подобным методом все строчки ниже текущей. Либо воспользоваться для поиска совпадений функцией `Find` объекта `Range`. Для более подробного ответа не хватает данных.

Comment: Долго будет лопатить все 80 000 записей. Массивом нужно. Хотя, автору, возможно, свсем другое требуется...

Comment: Ды я в курсе, но ведь подробностей почти нет. Предложил самый очевидный вариант